# jQuery append() html syntax behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning to use jquery and am making some test pages for practice.

For this example, I use jquery to bind a function, "showAddToDb()", to a button. When that button is pressed, jquery should append the following html form code into the div labeled by the id "memberContent" (which I have left out here).

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#addToDb').bind('click',showAddToDb);
 });
 function showAddToDb() {
        var form = $("<div></div>");
        var formName = "<div class=\"formRow\"><label for=\"name\">Name: </label><input class=\"nameInput\" type=\"text\" name=\"name\"/></div>";
        var formLocation = "<div class=\"formRow\"><label for=\"location\">Location: </label><input class=\"locationInput\" type=\"text\" name=\"location\"/></div>";
        var formDes = "<div class=\"formRow\"><label for=\"description\">Description: </label><textarea class=\"descriptionInput\" name=\"description\" rows=\"10\" maxlength=\"1000\"></textarea></div>";
        var formPrice = "<div class=\"formRow\"><label for=\"price\">Price: </label><input class=\"priceInput\" type=\"text\" name=\"price\"/></div>";
        var formSubmit = "<div class=\"formRow\"><button onclick=\"addToDb()\">Submit</button></div>";
        form.append(formName);
        form.append(formLocation);
        form.append(formDes);
        form.append(formPrice);
        form.append(formSubmit);
        $('#memberContent').append(form);
    }
```

The code above works, but I struggled to get it working and my question is why it works. To get it to work, I had to change the first line of the function from `var form = "<div></div>";` to `var form = $("<div></div>");`

I know that the dollar sign stands for a jquery call, but I'm not sure why I need that here in this particular case. Also, am I supposed to also wrap all the other vars with `$()` for appending? It works as is, but I have seen some examples online that do this without explaining why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't pass that string to jQuery, then all it is is a string. Note that later on you use the "form" variable as if it were a jQuery object:

```
form.append(formName);
```

so it had better be one!  You could also have introduced a new variable:

```
var $form = $(form); // assuming "form" was a plain string
```

And then:

```
$form.append(formName);
// etc, with "$form" instead of "form"
```

Some people like marking variables that hold jQuery objects by giving them names that start with a "$".  It's a matter of personal preference.

You don't have to wrap the other strings because they're being handed directly over to a jQuery API. That code will know what to do with them. However, if you did wrap them up as jQuery objects, then that would work too, again because jQuery would just do the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

*To get it to work, I had to change the first line of the function from `var form = "<div></div>";` to `var form = $("<div></div>");`*

that because you tried to use the `append` on a string in the first code, this will not work because the function is expecting a DOM object. when you use this `$("<div></div>");` you are turning a string into a DOM object, thus making the `append()` function call valid. if you used plain javascript to turn the string into a DOM object, you'll need the `createElement()` function.

this is plain javascript

```
var form = document.creatElement('div') // works
```

this is jQuery as you already know

```
var form = $('<div></div>'); // works
```

and this doesn't work with any DOM object functions

```
 var form = "<div></div>"; // won't work with .append()
```

the first two makes a DOM div object unlike `var form = "<div></div>";` which just creates a javascript string. if you want to use DOM object functions e.g. `append()` you need to turn your javascript variables into a DOM object like the first two examples.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your question has been answered by others. But since you mentioned that you are learning to use jQuery, `.bind` is deprecated, use `.on`. And you can use single quote to wrap your assigned strings so you don't need to escape the double quotes in the strings.

Comment: ah, I see. I won't use bind anymore then. Also, thanks for the tip about the double quotes. Escaping each and every one of them was such a pain, haha.